# Windows 10 Right click issue

Tags: windows, right-click

My windows OS build is 1809 and recently i have noticed that after right clicking and hovering over to New option freezes the menu or gives a lag to show available option.This started happen after I moved Camera roll and screenshot folder to a usb drive and deleted them and restored them back since screenshots were not being saved and saw this issue after the update.Is this a update issue or some fix that needs to be done ? I have tried ShellEXT and have 3rd party programs installed save for McAfee,Java,Python

Comment: Hard to say with so little infomation. Maybe your hard drive is slow, maybe is about to be full, etc; Please deliver specs of your computer, update dates, etc.

Comment: What you describe isn’t a known issue with 1809.  It is either an undiscovered unreported issue or an issue unique to your system

Comment: I would suggest open the registry editor - Regedit.exe.  Right click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and search for ShellNew.  For each entry you find check that the FileName, ItemName, iconpath values where exit looks OK.  I suspect that Explorer is trying to find a icon or a path under these keys that either doesn't exist, etc..

Comment: Right click menu delays are often related to Shell options or extensions. Try @HelpingHand's solution, and take a look at the program `ShellExt`

Comment: HDD is like 96% empty and tried shellext, no third app is installed save for java, python, McAfee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by deletion of System made/present folders like camera and screenshot. The issue was resolved after manual and external(downloading update from Microsoft servers instead from Windows settings app) update to Windows 10 V1909